# difference between pointing to the Strings and the reference of the String of the vector while iterating through the vector

Tags: rust

```
let mut vec: Vec<String>=Vec::new();
vec.push("one".to_string());
vec.push("two".to_string());
vec.push("three".to_string());
let mut word=String::new();
for indx in 0..vec.len(){
    word+=vec[indx]; //line no. 4 
 }
```

line no. 4 shows error to use **&vec[indx]** instead of **vec[indx]**.
please help me understand the reason behind it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you must read ownership rules in rust

String and Vec do NOT impl Copy trait
so if you write code like this

```
let val1 = String::from("Test");
let val2 = val1; // Ownership of "Test" moved to val2 and val1 is gone
```

assignment operator '=' over variables that do not impl copy trait move ownerships

so if you don't wanna change ownership you can borrow the value like this

```
let val1 = String::from("Test");
let val2 = &val1; // val2 access to Test by borrow the reference of value
```

a quick tip for easy understand when and which data type have not Copy trait

1. if data type have dynamic length like String, Vector and Map
2. if data type store in HEAP memory

remember if a data type don't impl copy trait it'll move ownership of value if you use assignment operator '='

[ownership rust](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch04-00-understanding-ownership.html)

Comment: understood. but in your second example I think you meant let val2 = &val1;

Comment: yes, i'll edit it