# Confuse about borrowing in Rust

Tags: rust, borrow-checker, ownership, ownership-semantics

I have 2 example code.

---

1st Example Code

```
fn main() {
    let mut s = String::from("hello");

    let r1 = &mut s;
    let r2 = & s;

    println!("{}", r2);
}
```

---

2nd Example Code

```
fn main() {
    let mut s = String::from("hello");

    let r1 = &mut s;
    let r2 = & s;

    println!("{}", r1);
}
```

---

What I confuse is why `1stExampleCode` work fine, but `2ndExampleCode` create compile error as below

`cannot borrow 's' as immutable because it is also borrowed as mutable`

As I know, in both Example code I borrow `r1` did a mutable borrow of `s` while `r2` did a immutable borrow of `s`. So why `1stExampleCode` is not error since `s` is borrowed as both `mutable` and `immutable` at the same time. Or because `r1` is not used so it's not create any error.

Comment: i think you can found your answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71634400/difference-between-pointing-to-the-strings-and-the-reference-of-the-string-of-th/71634795#71634795) rust built for safety and data-race it's not acceptable when you have two borrow at a same time that one of them is `mut` compiler can't guaranty that value will never change when you read it

Answer (score 4):

In the first example, the compiler is smart enough to know that the `r1` is not used anymore after it's initialized because it's never called anymore.
It also means the borrowed `s` is released after the initialized line of `r1` and can be borrowed by others. So `r2` can borrow it.

In the second example, `r1` is borrowing `s` value with mutable reference. A mutable reference can only be borrowed by one variable.
But `r2` borrowing `s` variable while `r1` still uses it in the `println!` line.

For more information, you can read this https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch04-02-references-and-borrowing.html

Answer (score 1):

The trick is that Rust refuses to have both borrows at once (because one is `mut`). However, in one case, Rust accepts the code because it can drop one of the borrows before the other one is given. That would be your first example. Indeed, the `r1` variable is dropped (implicitly, by Rust) just before `r2` is assigned, which is possible because you never use it again (in fact, you never use it at all, but whatever).

In the second case, however, Rust cannot do that, because between the creation and the usage of the first borrow, you create the second, that is, it's impossible to `drop` one when the other starts to be valid.